# Use require.js to load named TypeScript modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, amd, bundling-and-minification

**Brief problem description:** I'd like to use TypeScript to generate AMD-style *named* modules, which I then want to load from a bundled and minified file using requires.js.

**Questions:**

- Is that possible?
- Or do you suggest another approach?

I want to combine the benefits of having all scripts bundled and minified (so that no additional HTTP requests are necessary) with loading named AMD modules which are generated by TypeScript.

---

**Update:** I was thinking along the lines of the following JavaScript solution:

```
define("greeter", ["require", "exports", "jquery"], function(require, exports, $) {
    function greet() {
        alert("Hello World!");
    }

    exports.greet = greet;
});
```

Then I could bundle and minify the generated JavaScript modules into a file that could easily be cached by browsers. Also, require.js wouldn't have to go out there and grab the modules via several GET requests — they're already defined. Plus, I'd have all the advantages of using TypeScript to generate those modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this by using RequireJS directly in TypeScript.

There is a definition file for it and I've written an example for using raw [RequireJS in TypeScript](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201302/Blog/Using-RequireJS-and-Jquery-In-TypeScript/) (rather than import statements) with jQuery, that you might be able to adapt.

Here is the resulting TypeScript code...

```
///<reference path="require.d.ts" />
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(() => {
        alert('Your code executes after jQuery has been loaded.');
    });
});
```

If this doesn't do what you want, show me how you would do it in JavaScript and I'll happily supply the TypeScript equivalent.

Comment: I have updated my question and included a more detailed explanation. Is that possible or am I just making things up?

Comment: If you bundle and minify all your files, I would recommend just including those files in a script tag and ditch all module-loading altogether. That would be the simplest solution to reduce the requests (to 1 request).

Comment: So you're suggesting not to use external TypeScript modules at all? Instead, I could use internal TypeScript modules, right?

Comment: Alright, that sounds like a plan. However, do you know if it's possible to let TypeScript generate named AMD modules?

Comment: If you use external modules and `import` statements, all your TypeScript should work fine with RequireJS, straight out of the box. Just compile with the `--module amd` flag.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, and it works perfectly. TypeScript isn't generating *named* modules, though (notice the "greeter" name in my module above). Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: Ah I see - I don't know of a way.

Comment: In that case, I know that I haven't been overseeing something the entire time. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I am really wanting this feature to become part of the language, too. I made a post about it here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/541380